# Issues hooking into action for WordPress plugin updates

Tags: wordpress, plugins, webhooks, updates

I am trying to put together a WordPress plugin that will send a webhook when a plugin is updated.

I am hooking into upgrader_process_complete, and also tried upgrader_post_install but nothing seems to be working. There is no errors showing in the logs either.

Here is the plugin code:

```
// Webhook URL
define('WEBHOOK_URL', 'https://example.com');

// Hook into the plugin update process
add_filter('upgrader_post_install', 'webhook_on_plugin_update', 10, 3);

function webhook_on_plugin_update($response, $hook_extra, $result) {
    
    // Check if the update process is for a plugin
    if ($hook_extra['type'] === 'plugin' && $hook_extra['action'] === 'update') {
        // Get the updated plugin information
        $plugin_info = $hook_extra['plugins'][0];

       // Prepare data for the webhook payload
        $payload = array(
            'event' => 'plugin_updated',
            'plugin_name' => $plugin_info['Name'],
            'plugin_version' => $plugin_info['Version'],
            'timestamp' => current_time('timestamp'),
        );

        // Send the webhook
        send_webhook_request($payload);
    }

    return $response;
}

function send_webhook_request($payload) {
    // Use wp_remote_post to send the webhook request
    wp_remote_post(WEBHOOK_URL, array(
        'body' => json_encode($payload),
        'headers' => array('Content-Type' => 'application/json'),
    ));
}
```

Does anyone have any insights into hooking into the upgrader_post_install or upgrader_process_complete actions that would be helpful.

EDITED to add code with action

```
define('WEBHOOK_URL', 'https://example.com');

add_action('upgrader_process_complete', 'webhook_on_plugin_update', 150);

function webhook_on_plugin_update($upgrader_object, $options) {
    if ($options['type'] === 'plugin' && $options['action'] === 'update') {
        $plugin_info = get_plugin_data(WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/' . $options['plugins'][0]);

        $payload = array(
            'event' => 'plugin_updated',
            'plugin_name' => $plugin_info['Name'],
            'plugin_version' => $plugin_info['Version'],
            'timestamp' => current_time('timestamp'),
        );

        send_webhook_request($payload);
    }
}

function send_webhook_request($payload) {
    wp_remote_post(WEBHOOK_URL, array(
        'body' => json_encode($payload),
        'headers' => array('Content-Type' => 'application/json'),
    ));
}
```

Comment: The `upgrader_process_complete` action would be more appropriate for this than the `upgrader_post_install` filter. Can you please adjust your question to show the code you had for the action (or at the very least have code for both)?

Comment: Hi @Caleb, I edited my post showing what I had for upgrader_process_complete. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Can we split this into two problems: having code fire after a plugin updates, and calling a webhook. Are you able to get any code to fire after the update? Like just trying to log to disk maybe? If that's not working, you have one problem. Then, to your webhook, `wp_remote_post` returns the response or a WP_Error object, which you aren't currently doing anything with. Have you tried inspecting that?

Comment: @ChrisHaas just wanted to update you to let you know I figured it out and posted the answer in case you are interested in seeing how I fixed it.  I took a look at some other plugins to see what they did differently. Thank you for your time today, it's very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So, after taking a look at some other plugins and how they did it, I took a lead from the Activity Log plugin and after a few attempts I came up with this, which is working.

```
class Webhook_On_Update_Plugin {

    // Define the webhook URL where the update information will be sent
    const WEBHOOK_URL = 'https://example.com';

    public function __construct() {
        add_action('upgrader_process_complete', array($this, 'webhook_on_plugin_update'), 10, 2);
    }

    public function webhook_on_plugin_update($upgrader_object, $options) {
        error_log('webhook_on_plugin_update fired');
        // Check if the update process is for a plugin
        if ($options['type'] === 'plugin' && $options['action'] === 'update') {
            // Get the updated plugin information
            $plugin_info = get_plugin_data(WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/' . $options['plugins'][0]);

            // Prepare data for the webhook payload
            $payload = array(
                'event' => 'plugin_updated',
                'plugin_name' => $plugin_info['Name'],
                'plugin_version' => $plugin_info['Version'],
                'timestamp' => current_time('timestamp'),
            );

            // Send the webhook
            $this->send_webhook_request($payload);
            error_log('send_webhook_request fired');
        }
    }

    public function send_webhook_request($payload) {
        // Use wp_remote_post to send the webhook request
        wp_remote_post(self::WEBHOOK_URL, array(
            'body' => json_encode($payload),
            'headers' => array('Content-Type' => 'application/json'),
        ));
    }
}

// Instantiate the class
new Webhook_On_Update_Plugin();
```

This is was was received by the webhook

```
{
  "event": "plugin_updated",
  "plugin_name": "Child Theme Configurator",
  "plugin_version": "2.6.5",
  "timestamp": 1705358283
}
```

and this is what showed in the logs

```
[15-Jan-2024 22:38:03 UTC] webhook_on_plugin_update fired
[15-Jan-2024 22:38:03 UTC] send_webhook_request fired
```

This is the code from Activity Log which I looked at to try and figure it out.

```
public function hooks_plugin_install_or_update( $upgrader, $extra ) {
        if ( ! isset( $extra['type'] ) || 'plugin' !== $extra['type'] )
            return;

        if ( 'install' === $extra['action'] ) {
            $path = $upgrader->plugin_info();
            if ( ! $path )
                return;
            
            $data = get_plugin_data( $upgrader->skin->result['local_destination'] . '/' . $path, true, false );
            
            aal_insert_log(
                array(
                    'action' => 'installed',
                    'object_type' => 'Plugins',
                    'object_name' => $data['Name'],
                    'object_subtype' => $data['Version'],
                )
            );
        }

        if ( 'update' === $extra['action'] ) {
            if ( isset( $extra['bulk'] ) && true == $extra['bulk'] ) {
                $slugs = $extra['plugins'];
            } else {
                $plugin_slug = isset( $upgrader->skin->plugin ) ? $upgrader->skin->plugin : $extra['plugin'];

                if ( empty( $plugin_slug ) ) {
                    return;
                }

                $slugs = array( $plugin_slug );
            }
            
            foreach ( $slugs as $slug ) {
                $data = get_plugin_data( WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/' . $slug, true, false );
                
                aal_insert_log(
                    array(
                        'action' => 'updated',
                        'object_type' => 'Plugins',
                        'object_name' => $data['Name'],
                        'object_subtype' => $data['Version'],
                    )
                );
            }
        }
    }
public function __construct() {
add_action( 'upgrader_process_complete', array( $this, 'hooks_plugin_install_or_update' ), 10, 2 );
parent::__construct();
    }
```

Having looked back through the logs to see what errors my old code was spitting out, I found this which was telling me there was an issue with the number of arguments being passed to the webhook_on_plugin_update function. It would seem only one argument was being passed to the upgrader_process_complete action.

```
[15-Jan-2024 22:32:17 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function webhook_on_plugin_update(), 1 passed in /home/******/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 326 and exactly 3 expected in /home/******/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-total-plugin-update-notify/wp-total-plugin-update-notify.php:15
```

Thank you to those who replied, I do appreciate the time you took out of your day to reply to my query.